# Update sudoers file in multiple servers with a bash script

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo, passwd

I have 50 Linux servers and can login to the servers without root password (I know the password). Now I would like to add 3 lines in sudoers file on each servers. Obviously logging into 50 servers and adding lines are painful. Is there a different approach we can achieve this by a bash script or a loop?

Comment: Scp the new file to each server?

Comment: Ansible is designed to do exactly this.

Comment: This setup is for ansible only. I am tying to add ansible user in all 50 servers and want to update sudoers permissions on each server so that I can run my playbooks from control node.

Comment: There are various methods described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359404/ansible-best-practice-for-maintaining-list-of-sudoers

Answer (score 2):

Rather than editing `/etc/sudoers` directly:

Most Linux distributions support by default a modular sudo configuration by loading files / configuration snippets from drop-in directory via the [`#includedir`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers) directive.

Note the <kbd>#</kbd> in that is NOT A COMMENT marker.

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

That allows you to copy/upload the sudo directives you want to set as separate drop-in file, e.g. `/etc/sudoers.d/ansible-user` which is much easier to script and maintain than a single configuration file.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this.

Comment: I have added below line to /etc/sudoers.d/ansible-user file. It is not working.
ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Finally it worked when I renamed file name from 'ansible-user' to 'ansible'